# How to align the text on the right and the button on the left and make it responsive css

Tags: html, css

I have a card I want to align the text on the left and the button on the right with space between the two and put it responsive on the devices
knowing that the button I add the backgroud-image

here is what i tried but it is still not responsive

```css
.component {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.link {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: url("../../myicon.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  height: 24px;
  width: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div class="component">
  <div>
    <span class="">DEV</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="btn">
      <button><a  class='link'>Button </a></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not responsive"? The flex seems to work as you wish - putting the text on the left and the button on the right regardless of viewport size. By the way, you shouldn't nest interactive elements such as an `<a>` element inside a `<button>` element or vice versa.

Comment: when I reduce my screen or when I am in mobile version the button is not fixed it exceeds where it has my card. it exceeds the limits of card

Comment: Could you put up a snippet which demonstrates the problem as what we can try so far works OK.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this (tightly grouped)

```
<div class="component">
'    <span class="link">DEV</span>
    <div class="btn">
      <button>Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

but then
.

```
.btn {
  float : left;
}
```

or maybe you want the anchor to actually do something, so maybe `<a onclick="..." href="...">Dev</a>`. Always try to keep it simple. Each component - the container component, the span, the div, the button, the anchor should have its own thing. I can imagine more things being added to this container component in the future (an image, an ajax of imformation coming and so on), so the simpler it is now, the simpler it will be to adjust in the future.

Comment: Unknown property: 'align'scss(unknownProperties)

Comment: @wilfrid, thanks, I corrected it.

Comment: I already tried that but it doesn't work